# What is the name of this french food?

Tags: food-identification

One of my friends is in Paris (France), and he posted this photo from a restaurant there . Does anyone know the name of this dish ?

[image]

Comment: WOW, that totally looks NOT good.

Comment: Looks like a failed attempt to fancy up a humble fruit salad to me. Doubt it really has a name anywhere except for that restaurant. Though it is really hard to give a real answer without knowing what is under that cuckoo spit *cough* I mean foam...

Comment: I don't know but he said it's a main dish not an appetizer or a dessert . I know the foam (cuckoo spit :P ) hide the ingredient but maybe someone from Paris know what it is :)

Comment: It looks like a fruit salad with raw chicken.  And of course the "foam".  LOL  Actually the foam reminds me of the foam that's on top of fresh apple juice (from a juicer).

Comment: I don't see 'Main' written anywhere. It looks to me like: Baby Fennel, diced apple, grape fruit segments, lychee (raw chicken), basil oil and a clove of garlic. All guess work. I know if that was put down in front of me I would send it back is all...

Comment: Really? I see a white fish, that one that has the pink tinges to it, I can't remember its name right now. I don't think this dish will have some kind of name that will be used in any other restaurant anyway, this looks like it's trying to be Nouvelle cuisine, so finding the name probably won't help to find the dish elsewhere anyway. Best people to ask is the waitstaff, not cooking.se :)

Comment: Do you have the restaurant name? that would help narrow it down.

Answer (score 2):

If it is a french dish (they have other cuisines in Paris, yeah?) then it is likely to be a mix of poached (baby) vegetables, with or without some poached protein (fish or fowl). No fruit. These delicate veg dishes are prolific, hard to cook cos they depend on a carefully crafted stock and best quality veg (& little else, bar the molecular gastronomy nonsense foam). They can be a revelation in taste if done well and expertly, otherwise they look and taste like the remnants of stock-making day, that over boiled sludge in the bottom of your colander.

I doubt this dish has a name, as such. Obviously the menu named it, but in Larousse I'm guessing it would be just the standard poached veg.